# Stripe Alipay onboarding with v3 js API

Tags: stripe-payments, alipay

Trying to charge Alipay with Stripe, however it keeps reporting this error message. I can see the Alipay option is green in the Stripe Panel. Anyone got similar experience and solutions?

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

// Create a Stripe client
var stripe = Stripe('<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key'];?>');

stripe.createSource({
  type: 'alipay',
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'usd',
  redirect: {
    return_url: 'var_dump.php',
  },
}).then(function(result) {
  window.location=result.source.redirect.url;
});


</script>
```

the console error from api.stripe.com/v1

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Your Alipay onboarding is still pending review, so you can only create testmode Alipay sources. Please try again later or contact support@stripe.com with any questions.",
    "code": "pbl_pending"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common reason to get this error is if you have multiple Stripe accounts, and the API key you are using is not for the same account that was approved to accept Alipay payments.

If your API key is for the correct account, then you'll need to write into support to get this sorted.

Comment: Problem solved. Alipay requires a screencast of the application before they can approve the live source.